# UI freezes when at the particular task and only when accessing from terminal machine

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

For some reason User Interface freezes for 7-12 seconds when double click to open a PolicyNumber to display details.
And its only happens when accessing the application from the terminal machine. 
From the local server it works fine.

Interesting thing is if I keep open the same PolicyNumber right after I just close it - then it works fine, but if I wait 2-3 minutes and try to open the same PolicyNumber - then it freezes for approx 10-12 seconds.

I used SQL Profiler to track what is going on but couldn't find anything suspicious. Plus it seems like all sql statements and SP's are completed - but the UI still "thinking".

[image]

What would that be? What else should I check?

Comment: So, you only experience the lag on the term server when opening a PolicyNumber? Or do you experience lag overall? Is the term server half-way around the world or in the next room?

Comment: Its only happens on term server when opening a PolicyNumber. No lag overall. The data center is in the same city, so server is next to. 
Thanks

Comment: What was the duration of the query in the trace?  If it was significantly less than 10-12 seconds, then your problem isn't with SQL Server.

Comment: The duration was max 5 sec.  But what should I do? Where should I look for the solution? Thanks

Comment: What kind of memory allocation do you have for the instance?  It sounds like the query is dropping out of cache and has to be read from disk after a certain period.

Comment: Max server memory is 114668 MB. I'd say its a lot of power behind. (on production server)